# Understanding "invalid decimal literal"

Tags: python

```
100_year = date.today().year - age + 100
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

I'm trying to understand what the problem is.

Comment: Variables' name cannot start with a digit/number

Comment: Had this error when I ran Python 2 code with Python 3, and there were arbitrary precision intervals in the code, meaning: integer + big L at the end like "0L". Just change back to Python 2 then.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Python identifiers can not start with a number.

The 'arrow' points to `year` because [underscore is a valid thousands separator in Python >= 3.6](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0515/), so `100_000` is a valid integer literal.

Comment: So you might use `year_100` instead.

Comment: 10 years of python coding and I still make this mistake.  D'oh!

Answer (score 7):

Sadly in python you cant make variables that start with numbers so therefore you could use something like this:

```
hundred_year = date.today().year - age + 100
```

Answer (score 0):

I received the error, because I had forgotten to insert a '*' between the number and the variable; that happened because I had copied a formula from WolframAlpha, where blanks between values and/or variables are "automagically" interpreted as multiplication signs.