# Fixtures are not working after Django squashmigrations

Tags: django, django-migrations

I just squashed a lot of migrations in Django 4.0.x.
Now when running the migrations I get the following error:

```
  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.10/x64/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Django-4.0.3-py3.9.egg/django/db/migrations/loader.py", line 120, in load_disk

    migration_module = import_module(migration_path)

  File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.10/x64/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 846, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 983, in get_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 913, in source_to_code
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/runner/work/backend/backend/general/migrations/0001_squashed_0019_merge_0018_auto_20220226_2311_0018_auto_20220228_2343.py", line 42
    code=general.migrations.0004_initial_general.Migration.load_data,
                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

The according code lines in the migration file is:

```
        migrations.RunPython(
            code=general.migrations.0004_initial_general.Migration.load_data,
        ),
```

I am totally lost here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the top of your squashed migration file - you should find a comment that reads something like this:

```
# Functions from the following migrations need manual copying.
# Move them and any dependencies into this file, then update the
# RunPython operations to refer to the local versions:
# general.migrations.0004_initial_general
```

You should also have seen a notice [printed to your console](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/core/management/commands/squashmigrations.py#L241-L246) when you generated the migrations, alerting you that manual modification of the generated file is needed.

This is happening because you have defined some custom migration functions in that migration, which Django was not able to migrate automatically. You need to manually copy the `load_data` function from `0004_initial_general.py` into this squashed migration file, and then replace the reference to it in the `RunPython` call.

Answer (score 0):

As I could find in this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/59813844/17881270
Python identifiers can not start with a number.

Hope that could help you. Rename them in migration table and that directory and your squash.
Or maybe you can use getattr function.

Comment: This is auto generated by Django migrations, so I think there is something else going on.

Comment: May I see full file?

Comment: Variable names cannot start with a digit in Python, but filenames are okay, so that's not the issue.