# invalid decimal literal when importing csv via pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

not sure if something has changed within pandas but all of a sudden I am unable to import my .csv file using pd.read_csv due to the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\Admin\Documents\GitHub\REPLete> python cust.csv UK
  File "C:\Users\Me\Documents\GitHub\REPLete\cust.csv", line 61

97,1652223600,17927711,Paperclips,1w
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal
```

This occurs on the first occurrence of where there is both [a-z] and [0-9] in a single field. Almost as if Pandas is trying to convert it into a Decimal but it can't because there is a non-decimal character...

The exact code used is as follows:

```
df = pd.read_csv('cust.csv')
```

The first few lines of the CSV are as follows:

```
Completed,Action Required,Addr1,Addr2,Addr3,Addr4,Addr5,Postcode,DT_Set,Pri,DT_Due,Tel,NOTES:,NHS_Org,Company,Contact_Email,Billing_Email,Contact_FirstName,Contact_LastName,Interested in Demo,Date Scheduled,Time of Demo,Lead name
,,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,XYZ XYZ,,,,1279621900,,RP0005,New Road Surgery,xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx,Jeremy,Fisher,SPEAKING TO MICHAEL 10y,,,
,,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,XYZ XYZ,1649075159.0,97.0,1964646000.0,1933234900,,RP0006,Long Road Medical,xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx,Marjorie,Stewart-Baxter,,,,
,,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,Xyz Xyz,XYZ XYZ,1648635737.0,97.0,1964214000.0,2476674123,,RP0008,Rusty Spoon Medical Centre,xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx,xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx;xxx.xxx@xxx.xxx,Hubert,Cumberdale,ALREADY GOT IT,,,
```

How can I force read_csv to interpret everything as a string / object?
I will selectively cast the fields using df.astype that I need to be Integer/Float etc.

Hope someone can help!

Cheers,
Luke.

Comment: can you provide the first few lines of the csv?

Comment: Hia, have just updated the question with that info

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you're using python to execute a .csv file instead of the python script. **Just use the .py file instead of `python cust.csv UK`**. I don't believe it's pandas converting the value and giving you that error but because it's a known restriction that variable names in python can't start with a number see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813807/understanding-invalid-decimal-literal).

If you want pandas to convert all columns as a string/object/float etc. then use read_csv(x, dtype="str") or specify a dict for each column to be a specific type by read_csv(x, dtype={'a': 'obj', 'b': 'str'})

I hardly doubt you even needed this answer but in case someone else stumbles on this then here ya go bud!