# SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal

Tags: python

[image: Example of the issue]

I was trying to make an module then import it. Why am I receiving this error above?

The code:

```
def convert_to_celsius(fahrenheit: float) -> float:
    """Return the number of Celsius degrees equivalent to fahrenheit
    degrees,

    >>>convert_to_celsius(75)
    23.88888888888889
    """
    return (fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0 / 9.0

def above_freezing(celsius: float) -> bool:
    """Return True iff temperature celsius degrees is above freezing.

    >>>above_freezing(5.2)
    True
    >>>above_freezing(-2)
    False
    """
    return celsius > 0
```

Comment: Check out this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59813807/understanding-invalid-decimal-literal

Comment: Show us the contents of the module you are trying to import. Preferrably as formatted code, [not an image](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: A link doesn't count towards satisfying [mre] rules: Enough code to demonstrate the problem needs to be included *as text* **in the question** itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python identifiers can not start with a number.

[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-python/#:~:text=A%20string%20literal%20can%20be,Python3](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/literals-in-python/#:%7E:text=A%20string%20literal%20can%20be,Python3)